# Read text from image using OCR for the image which have two columns or three columns of data using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

In the  example image (just a reference, my images will be of same pattern)  a page which have full horizontal text and other have two horizontal column of text.

[image]

How to automatically detect the pattern of the document and read one after the other column of data in python?.

I am using Tesseract OCR with Psm 6, where it is reading horizontally which is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

One way to accomplish this is using morphological operations and contour detection.

With the former you essentially "bleed" all characters into a big chunky blob. With the latter, you locate these blobs in your image and extract the ones that seem interesting (meaning: big enough).[image: extracted contours]

Script used:

```
import cv2
import sys

SCALE = 4
AREA_THRESHOLD = 427505.0 / 2

def show_scaled(name, img):
    try:
        h, w  = img.shape
    except ValueError:
        h, w, _  = img.shape
    cv2.imshow(name, cv2.resize(img, (w // SCALE, h // SCALE)))

def main():
    img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
    img = img[10:-10, 10:-10] # remove the border, it confuses contour detection
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    show_scaled("original", gray)

    # black and white, and inverted, because
    # white pixels are treated as objects in
    # contour detection
    thresholded = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
                gray, 255,
                cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,
                25,
                15
            )
    show_scaled('thresholded', thresholded)
    # I use a kernel that is wide enough to connect characters
    # but not text blocks, and tall enough to connect lines.
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (13, 33))
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresholded, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    show_scaled("closing", closing)

    for contour in contours:
        convex_contour = cv2.convexHull(contour)
        area = cv2.contourArea(convex_contour)
        if area > AREA_THRESHOLD:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [convex_contour], -1, (255,0,0), 3)

    show_scaled("contours", img)
    cv2.imwrite("/tmp/contours.png", img)
    cv2.waitKey()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then all you need is to compute the bounding box of the contour, and cut it from the original image. Add a bit of a margin and feed the whole thing to tesseract.

Comment: How to deal this problem: the two columns are not surrounded by two contours respectively but as a whole by only one?

Comment: Try making the structuring element thinner.

Comment: @deets, the script is working great, but how do i crop the text boxes using python and create new images from the boxes?

Comment: That’s really basic OpenCV and numpy  stuff. Read through a few tutorials.

Comment: can someone update this code to work with opencv v4 and above, please

Comment: @Dimitar nothing in this code is especially version dependent. What parts of it give you trouble, and what have you researched on the documentation of those calls?

Comment: @deets, this line of code `im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` its getting me error in opencv v4

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of that method, and how it has changed between versions? Have you looked at the documentation of *older* versions (3 or 2) how that method *used* to behave, to get an understanding of how the behaviour has changed, and what to do about that?

Comment: To get past the error in OpenCV 4, remove `im2, ` from the beginning of the line that calls `findContours`.

Comment: @deets how do u fixed AREA_THRESHOLD , what any geeral formula for keeping area threshold

Comment: @k_p based on the actual data. That was just what the concrete example suggested. So no, there is no general formula. At least not right here, right now. You could of course create one based on scan resolution, and the concrete layout used, including margins etc, but that's a lot of effort, and not worth it IMHO.

Comment: and in this case after getting contour how you are appying OCR , can u add that part for more clearity

Comment: I won't change this recipe, as that's not the question that was asked. *If* I find time, I'll look into your other question.