# How do you crop an image from bounding box and create new image for each box

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr

This is my image
[image: book image]

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49823451/read-text-from-image-using-ocr-for-the-image-which-have-two-columns-or-three-col) question to create those boxes, but I am not good with python. How do I now create 3 images from the 3 boxes that i have created? I searched the internet and i can't find the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15589825/8353711). This is what you required?

Comment: I am not very good with python as I said. When I try this code i get `NameError: name 'y' is not defined`

Comment: Those are dimensions of image you want to crop.

Comment: I have no idea how to get the dimensions of the boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the below code. I have followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49825412/8353711) you have provided in question.

```
var=1
for contour in contours:
    convex_contour = cv2.convexHull(contour)
    area = cv2.contourArea(convex_contour)
    if area > AREA_THRESHOLD:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [convex_contour], -1, (255,0,0), 3)

        # get rectangle bounding contour
        [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite("crop"+str(var)+".png", crop_img)
        var+=1
```

This will save the cropped images in current program running location in `.png` format

Comment: that works great the only problem i have right now is that the `var` variable is not consistent. What i mean is that first image is the box on the bottom right and then the box on the left side and then the box on the right upper part, is there a way to keep the boxes from left-top to right-bottom, so the code can read them in order after that? thanks!

Comment: `var` is used just to give naming for files. The order of cropped images is depend on how the `contours` are sorted.